# static int arr[10] memory address always ends in 060

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I have a c program that looks like this

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SOME_VAR 10

static int heap[SOME_VAR];


int main(void) {
    printf("%p", heap);
    return 0;
}
```

and outputs this when I run the compiled program a few times

```
0x58aa7c49060
0x56555644060
0x2f8d1f8e060
0x92f58280060
0x59551c53060
0xd474ed6e060
0x767c4561060
0xf515aeda060
0xbe62367e060
```

Why does it always end in 060? And is the array stored in heap?

Edit: I am on Linux and I have ASLR on. I compiled the program using gcc

Comment: What operating system?  What compiler?

Comment: The variable is not in the heap, it is in the data or bss section of the program's address space, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable. My guess is that the program will always be placed at a memory address at a certain boundary, e.g. dividable by 0x1000, and the variable is placed by the compiler at a fixed offset in the program's address space.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The addresses differ because of ASLR (Address space layout ramdomization). Using this, the binary can be mapped at different locations in the virtual address space.

The variable `heap` is - in contrast to it's name - not located on the heap, but on the `bss`. The offset in the address space is therefore constant.

Pages are mapped at page granularity, which is 4096 bytes (hex: 0x1000) on many platforms. This is the reason, why the last three hex digits of the address is the same.

When you did the same with a *stack* variable, the address could even vary in the last digits on some platforms (namely linux with recent kernels), because the stack is not only mapped somewhere else but also receives a random offset on startup.

Comment: ASLR randomize base of loading as I remember. Section address are based on that address.

Comment: I am using a book on object oriented ANSI-C programming by Axel-Thobias Schreiner. The book is written in something like 1993. Do you know if the memory layout was different back then? If it was not, why might he have named the variable `heap` when it is not in heap?

Comment: Does 4096 translate into 060 in some way or does 0x1000 translate into 060 otherwise I do not understand what you mean by that being the reason for the ending? I thought it might have to do with the size of the array being something that is translated into 060 in hexadecimal from, e.g. decimal

Comment: @linuxlmao The offset is for example 14060, so when you add a multiple of a page size (0x1000), the last three digits remain `060`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Windows, the reason is [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) structure.

Your `heap` variable is stored in `.data` section of file and its address is calculated based on start of this section. Each section is loaded in an address independently, but its starting address is multiple of page size. Because you have no other variables, its address is probably start of `.data` section, so its address will be multiple of chunk size.

For example, this is the table of the compiled Windows version of your code:
[image: sections]
The `.text` section is were your compiled code is and `.data` contains your `heap` variable. When your PE is loaded into memory, sections are loaded in different address and which is returned by `VirtualAlloc()` and will be multiple of page size. But address of each variable is relative to start of section that is now a page size. So you will always see a fixed number on lower digits. Since the relative address of `heap` from start of section is based on compiler, compile options, etc. you will see different number from same code but different compilers, but every time what will be printed is fixed.

When I compile code, I noticed `heap` is placed on `0x8B0` bytes after start of `.data` section. So every time that I run this code, my address end in `0x8B0`.

Comment: I am using a book on object oriented ANSI-C programming by Axel-Thobias Schreiner. The book is written in something like 1993. Do you know if the memory layout was different back then? If it was not, why might he have named the variable `heap` when it is not in heap?

Comment: @linuxlmao It may well have been different. In 1993, Windows was a 16-bit operating system, with [memory segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) and all sorts of confusing stuff. It was *not* a 32-bit, flat-memory architecture as it is now. But these types of things are why asking/answering general questions about the layout of a program binary in memory is not useful. Understand what the C language standard guarantees to you *in general*, and that's all you need to know. Only worry about the actual layout if you're debugging a specific problem, then use a debugger

Comment: no, the variable shouldn't be created on heap even on older systems because it wasn't allocated with malloc and has static storage duration

Comment: @Afshin I'm addressing the OP's comment above

Comment: @phuclv sorry, because you were not mentioned him, I thought you were addressing me. :)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler happened to put `heap` at offset 0x60 bytes in a data segment it has, possibly because the compiler has some other stuff in the first 0x60 bytes, such as data used by the code that starts the `main` routine. That is why you see “060”; it is just where it happened to be, and there is no great significance to it.

Address space layout randomization changes the base address(es) used for various parts of program memory, but it always does so in units of 0x1000 bytes (because this avoids causing problems with alignment and other issues). So you see the addresses fluctuate by multiples of 0x1000, but the last three digits do not change.

The definition `static int heap[SOME_VAR];` defines `heap` with static storage duration. Typical C implementations store it in a general data section, not in the heap. The “heap” is a misnomer for memory that is used for dynamic allocation. (It is a misnomer because `malloc` implementations may use a variety of data structures and algorithms, not limited to heaps. They may even use multiple methods in one implementation.)